# Why am I receiving LazyStopLoader exception in my TomEE log?

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception, apache-tomee, catalina

I am running my application on TomEE and am recently receiving following exception in my log. I could not find much on the Internet. Does anyone have any idea of its root cause?

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase backgroundProcess
WARNING: Exception processing loader 
org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopLoader@34a94832 background process
java.lang.NullPointerException
```